# Linux how to run cat and unlink after one another in background process

Tags: php, linux, unix, merge, background-process

I have multiple chunk of file that should be merged into one file, and after it's done I would like to delete the pieces. How can I achieve that?
I tried

```
(cat 511MB.zip0 511MB.zip1 511MB.zip2 511MB.zip3 511MB.zip4 511MB.zip5 > 511MB.zip; unlink 511MB.zip0; unlink 511MB.zip1; unlink 511MB.zip2; unlink 511MB.zip3; unlink 511MB.zip4; unlink 511MB.zip5;) &
```

something like that it's a hit and miss, I mean if cat is not finished yet and it delete the pieces already, then it won't make a complete file.
So how can I start unlink after the cat is finished?

note that this command I will run it in PHP using exec(); I need it to run in background process so the user experience is smooth (after files uploaded, user can move to different page while the file is merging)

Comment: He must have used a file splitter before transfer for some bandwidth reason.

Comment: @SparKot I realized that after I posted.

Comment: `&` puts it to background. Redirect outputs from `stdout` and `stderr` to a log file.

Answer (score 2):

For goodness sake, use variables:

```
(files="511MB.zip0 511MB.zip1 511MB.zip2 511MB.zip3 511MB.zip4 511MB.zip5"
 cat $files > 511MB.zip; unlink $files) &
```

That's basic DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) stuff.  And if `unlink` really only takes one file at a time, use a `for` loop (but then, why not use `rm` instead of `unlink`?).  And if the names contain spaces, use an array.  Still go DRY!

The semicolon between the `cat` and the `unlink` ensures sequential execution; the unlinking will not start until the concatenation is complete.  You don't need to do anything else.

You would run into problem if you ran the `cat` on its own in background:

```
# !!BAD!!
(files="511MB.zip0 511MB.zip1 511MB.zip2 511MB.zip3 511MB.zip4 511MB.zip5"
 cat $files > 511MB.zip &
 unlink $files) &
# !!BAD!!
```

Comment: since we're using the variable files, what happened if several event happened at the same time? example uploading 5 files, so there are 5 files to be merged? and what do you mean to use array if the file have spaces?

Comment: @Harts: what do you mean by 'several events happen at the same time'?  You might have multiple sets of compressed files, but from somewhere, you know the list of files to be concatenated into a single big zip file.  An array in `bash` would be `files=(511MB.zip0 511MB.zip1 ... 511MB.zip5)`.  You'd then use `"${files[@]}" to reference the list of file names.  Done properly, this will preserve spaces in the file names — which is why you'd use it.  With the example, there are no spaces to worry about.

Comment: I mean e.g: I upload 3 500MB files (A, B, C).. so it will be a.zip0, a.zip1, .. b.zip0, b.zip1, and so on. so, and then after the upload finish, through ajax call, I will call on exec function for each files, in this case there will be 3 files being called simultaneously or almost at the same time. which means we will use the same variable files = a.zip0 a.zip1 for the first one, and if it's not finished yet, there will be another call of exec() --> files = b.zip0 b.zip1 ...

Comment: You will end up with three separate processes running.  One will be handling `a.zip0` .. `a.zip5`; one will be handling `b.zip0` .. `b.zip5`; and the other `c.zip0` .. `c.zip5`.  Each process has its own variable with its own list of files; each is independent of each of the other processes.  It is important to understand how the processes are working.   (And you really should use `rm` instead of `unlink`, I think.)

Comment: yes, I'm using rm seems like it's better to handle multiple files, it's just still don't know how to do files with space

Comment: `(files=("space file.zip0" "space file.zip1" "space file.zip2"); cat "${files[@]}" > "space file.zip"; rm "${files[@]}") &`.

Answer (score 1):

By using `&&` instead of `;` to separate your commands you make sure that the unlinks happen after a successful run of `cat`.

```
cat 511MB.zip0 511MB.zip1 511MB.zip2 511MB.zip3 511MB.zip4 511MB.zip5 > 511MB.zip && unlink 511MB.zip0 && unlink 511MB.zip1 && unlink 511MB.zip2 && unlink 511MB.zip3 && unlink 511MB.zip4 && unlink 511MB.zip5
```

Comment: The semicolon forces sequential execution; the unlinks won't happen until the cat completes.

Comment: But if cat fails, the unlinks will still happen.

Comment: True, but the issue wasn't "if `cat` fails" but "if `cat` has not completed"...and the semicolon ensures that `cat` has completed.  The `&&` is not wrong — but isn't necessary.